# api or implementation for dependencies in my own library?

Tags: android, gradle

Is there some good reason to use api over implementation in gradle when using your own library ? Is there any good reason to use it in some other situation ? I could not find answer in other questions about it. Or its just when you have to because of transition from using of compile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides your own library one the most relevant situation where I see it useful is when you have a multi-module project. In this kind of projects you most likely end up having modules that have dependencies of other modules and since you might want that gradle recompiles your modules dependencies if there is any change in those modules `api` is the answer.

`api` is the equivalent of `compile`, and `implementation` was added to improve gradle builds by not having to recompile every dependency but only the ones that needs to be recompiled.

The following articles are a good source of information about it, and they are very concise.

[Implementation vs API dependency](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2017/06/14/androidstudio3/)

[Implementation Vs Api in Android Gradle plugin 3.0](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa)

**Update:**

From gradle docs:

> The api bucket is used to declare dependencies that should
>   transitively be visible by downstream consumers when they are
>   compiled. The implementation bucket is used to declare dependencies
>   which should not leak into the compile classpath of consumers (because
>   they are purely internal details).

This means that if your own library wants to expose any dependency to its consumers you should use `api`. Any dependencies with `api` in your own library will be part of the compile classpath of the app consuming your own library. With `implementation` you wont expose the dependencies you are using in your own library to the app that is consuming it.

You can see this being applied in well known libraries like [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/build.gradle) for instance. Where the "core" butterknife module, which is the one the consumer app adds as dependency, is exposing `butterknife-annotations` to the consumer through `api project(':butterknife-annotations')`. And this is what allows the consumer use the binding annotations from `butterknife` such as `@BindView`.

If the `butterknife-annotations` were added in `butterknife` with `implementation` instead of `api`, the consumer app will not be able to use those binding annotations. Because the `butterknife-annotations` will no longer be part of the compile classpath of the consumer app.

Comment: "Besides my own library"... so if I have my own library, for what reason would be good to use api ? Still don't get it actually from your text... So you mean some chain of depended local libraries or what ? module A depends on module B and that on module c so in this case is some problem when I use implementation ? Or when is problem when I use implementation and have to use api ? I have actually all this situations im my projects tried it with api for my shared dependencies and but implementation work good too, so was curious about it... looks like if you have done it right you dont' need api

Comment: Updated the answer since I couldn't fit the answer here in the comments due to the char limitation.

Comment: Ok now you got me with the example you wrote thanks !